# Arduino with FTDI cable - USB port error

Tags: arduino, ftdi

This is my first time using FTDI with Arduino.

[image]
[image]

I'm using the [SparkFun EL Sequencer](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11323) which uses and embedded ATMega328p. I hooked it up to my USB port using [this FTDI cable](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9718). When I try to upload my code: I get the following error:

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00
```

Debug mode:

```
avrdude: usbdev_open(): did not find any USB device "usb"
```

I've used my regular USB cable to successfully program my UNO from this machine (Win 7) before. No problem there.

With the sequencer I see the machine detecting a connection on COM 7 when I plug in the new device. I've tried pressing RESET on the Arduino prior to uploading, which I've seen in some other posts.

Am I missing something here? The description of the cable seems to imply that I don't need any other hardware.

Comment: This FTDI cable is a USB to serial port converter.  Which means you'd be trying to program your Arduino through its serial port, not USB.  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: avrdude calling a function named *usbdev_open()* sounds a lot like an incorrect command line.  As far as AVRdude is concerned, your device is serial, not USB.

Comment: @ChrisStratton btw, multi +1s for the helpful comments and not casting a down-vote. side-bar discussion from [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2740/why-are-electronics-se-questions-getting-down-voted-so-often).

Comment: Mando: I assumed because the cable had a USB connector on the other end that it would work. I have the FTDI driver installed on my machine for my old UNO, via usb. As to usb/serial - I just press the upload button, not sure.

Comment: Try the same settings you use with the uno, or even better, try those for duemilanova.  Your error strongly suggests something else was used.  FYI the Uno does not use the FTDI driver.

Comment: Well changing board types didn't work :( I've tried several.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error on the El Sequencer board silk-screen - the pins on the FTDI cable are reversed.

Answer (score 1):

usbdev_open() is a function in the avrdude sources currently used only the in the USB driver for the AVRISP mkII, which is not something you would ordinarily deal with during routine sketch deployment.

However, this does seem to be the default programmer selection under the programmers-> menu for use when burning bootloaders to new unitialized chips.

Thus it appears you have executed "burn bootloader" from the menu rather than pushing the upload button on your sketch.  Or else you have done some similarly atypical operation which tries to use such a USB programmer rather than talk to an Arduino bootloader over a (USB emulated) serial port as you should be doing.

Comment: I have not executed "burn bootloader" form the menu. Perhaps a setting for another board will work, as previously commented. I'll give that a try.